# Rails Jquery broken on AWS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I deployed a rails application to aws (elastic beanstalk) and all of my javascript broke. I keep getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` in the browser console. This error disapears when I remove all js from my rails project. When I only have `//= require jquery` in my application.js the error appears. I have no idea where to even start debugging this. This error does not occur on my development server.

**EDIT:**

I defined the version of jquery-rails in my gemfile and now its working.

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.2.2'
```

Comment: Is that the only output which you have in the console? Does the app works in production ENV on your localhost?

Comment: The app works in production on localhost. It doesn't break until its up on aws

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with a recent version of the uglifier gem. Update uglifier to at least 3.1.1 and the issue will go away.

The issue was tracked [here](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/110).